# Mouse overtaking in two iMacs

Tags: imac, bluetooth, mouse, monterey, magic-trackpad

I have two iMac computers in my office and both of them use trackpads. Recently, I started to notice some weird behaviours with the trackpad. The trackpad suddenly stops working, and it seems that the trackpad of my other iMac overtakes the current trackpad. I have two people using these two iMacs, and sometimes they need to fight over the control of the trackpad. When the other mouse stops controlling one of the computers the main mouse stops working; turning it off and on again doesn't work, and connecting it back to the computer doesn't work as well. Both of the trackpads are fully charged, and they are as well connected to their respective computers. I checked in the Bluetooth settings sections and made sure to disconnect both trackpads from the computers, but It didn't work. I also decided to use another mouse to see if there would be a difference, but no luck. The issue persists to this day. The only temporary solution is to turn off the computer completely and turn it on back again. The computers are separated by a distance of 3m(9.84ft). I am using macOS Monterey 12.4 in both iMacs

Comment: Are they both signed into the same AppleID?

Comment: Yes, both iMacs have the same Apple ID

Comment: If these are Apple Magic Trackpads, then leave them plugged in via USB, and they won't use Bluetooth. My TrackPad's been plugged in for several years.

Comment: The issue still persists even if the magic trackpads are connected to USB.

Comment: Check if you have Universal Control enabled on your iMacs: https://support.apple.com/kb/HT212757

Comment: Yes. My universal control is enabled. I will disabled it. Hopefully this will solve the problem